# Java - How to create a loop for TextFields?

Tags: java, javafx

Basically, I would like to make a loop which would change the name of every TextField to a name stored in a folder. I fully understand how to make loops for int values, but completely don't know how to make it to affect a methods (like I show it below). Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Check the code and I am sure you will understand what I mean

```
@FXML
private TextField t1;

@FXML
private TextField t2;

// etc...

@FXML
void music(ActionEvent event) {

    if (event.getSource() == dmusic) {
        File folder = new File("C:\\eclipse\\MP2");
        File[] list = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(list[i].getName());

            // Here i would like to update TextField name for every "t" method like I did below, but without writing it all the time.

        }

        //      t1.setText(list[0].getName());  // can't make infinite "t"'s and would like to make it in a loop
        //      t2.setText(list[1].getName());
        //      t3.setText(list[2].getName());
        //      t4.setText(list[3].getName());
        //      t5.setText(list[4].getName());
        //      t6.setText(list[5].getName());
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an arraylist

```
Arraylist<TextField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
<add TextFields to arraylist>
```

and then use

```
for(TextField field : fields) {
    field.setText("");
}
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i< fields.size(); i++){
    fields.get(i).setText("");
}
```

to access your individual text fields.

Comment: Thank you, i will try :)

Comment: Why an `ArrayList`? `Arrays.asList(...)`; This is more convenient than n calls to `add`. Alternatively an array could be used: `TextField[] fields = new TextField[]{ ... };`

Comment: I do not have a reason for choosing ArrayList over an array in this instance. Either would work.